# Getting field value in controller

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to get value of field in controller.
could you please help me?

here is my form code:

```
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
                     'id' => 'request-form',
                     'action' => 'site/request_page',
                     'method' => 'post',
                    'fieldConfig' => ['autoPlaceholder' => false]
                ]);
?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'workroom_id')->label(FALSE) ?>
```

and this is my controller code:

```
public function actionRequest_page() {

   echo Yii::$app->request->post('workroom_id');

    die();
```

}

But I got nothing in result.

Answer (score 1):

1. write workroom_id in safe rule like this-

   ```
   public function rules()
   {
       return [
           [['workroom_id'],'safe']
       ];
   }
   ```
2. Use bellow code -

   ```
   echo Yii::$app->request->post('MODEL_NAME')['workroom_id'];
   ```

Comment: no need to declare rules. he doesn't validate or fill the model in `site/request_page`.

Comment: could you please vote may question? I'm question ban :-(

Answer (score 0):

You should expand your action form-attribute. By using [`Url::to()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to()-detail) for instance. As in `echo \yii\helpers\Url::to(['site/request_page']);`

And access your post data differently. Try `var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post());` to see what your form data looks like. The other answer shows how to access it correctly.

The docs have an excellent starting place for [`working with forms`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-forms.html).

Comment: could you please vote may question? I'm question ban :-(

Comment: Could you give some feedback as to how you are progressing?